# Android show simple Toast on each calling Fragment on ViewPager

Tags: android

you suppose i have two fragment on `viewpager` which i can switch between them by swipe, for example `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`,

what i want to that when i swipe? i want to show toast between switch on them, for example when i swipe to switch on Fragment1, application show toast, or when i swipe to switch on Fragment2 application show toast, and again, show toast each showing and switching between fragments,

how can i do that? i can't find any documentation about this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Show your Toast Here like
        Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(),"Some string", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and if you want some method's inside your Fragments use this in every fragment whereever you want to show toast

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
}
```

Comment: is any other solution instead of viewpager listener?

Comment: may i ask why ?

Comment: using fragment methods to know this fragment is called

Comment: Thanks, problem recolved,your post accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 viewpagerEvent.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
             //toast message here

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

set `OnPageChangeListener` on `ViewPager` to get callback when page changed/scrolled or selected.

```
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Show fragment change/switch toast 
    Toast.makeText(this,"Fragment1", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to make condition for Both Fragment while on page changed. try below code on your Activity Class.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         if(position == 0)
                // Toast For Fragment 1
         if(position == 1)
                // Toast For Fragment 2
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```